# How do I get the default font for Swing JTabbedPane labels?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, look-and-feel

Does the text in Swing components have a default font?  In particular, what about tab labels on `JTabbedPane`s?

I'm working on a mock-up of a GUI made with Swing and want it to blend it with a screen image I grabbed of a Swing app.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on the Look and Feel. If it's an application you've written, get the values from `UIManager.getDefaults().getFont("TabbedPane.font")`

Comment: Yes, thanks, that worked, although you forgot a pair of parentheses:

     UIManager.getDefaults().getFont("TabbedPane.font")

It turned out to be Arial Bold, as I thought (for what it's worth).

Comment: How do you determine the appropriate keys for other swing components?

Comment: You can get the font for other components by changing 'TabbedPane' to the element type you're interested in.  For instance, I just found that the 'ToolTip.font' is 'Dialog'.

Answer (score 3):

The [UIManager Defaults](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=uimanager-defaults) shows what the values are for all properties for all components (including "TabbedPane.font").

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer of Reverend Gonzo, this piece of code lets you know what keys are in the UIDefaults. As the keys are self-explanatory, you know what key you can use. I had to know the key for the JTextField font, for example, and could only find it this way.

```
Set<Object> keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keySet();
for (Object key : keys) {
     if (key instanceof String && ((String) key).contains("font")) {
          System.out.println(key + "=" + UIManager.getDefaults().get(key));
     }
}
```

If you're looking for a font, in your case, just cast the key to a String and check whether it contains the word "font". This way you narrow the set of keys you have potential interest for.

I got a list

- Menu.font=...
- TextField.font=...
- RadioButtonMenuItem.font=...
- ToolTip.font=...
- TitledBorder.font=...
- ...
- TabbedPane.font=...
- ...

And thus you would need to pick TabbedPane.font.

Comment: Tried this on Java8 but only got a reduced subset of items. Changed the approach to assign the result of `getDefaults()` to a `Hashtable`, created an iterator and then checked its keys just as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the 'Look and Feel' you are using, but for me Swing's default font is

DejaVu Sans - Plain

For most components the font size defaults to around 12 or 13

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's Arial.  That's what [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com) tells me and it looks right.

Answer (score -3):

The Java GUI default font is "Helvetica", bold size 9, color gray.

Comment: that's wrong in its absoluteness: as others already correcty answered, fonts depend on LAFs and/or OS setting