# java swing components: binding properties such as font and background color

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a program in java with several Jpanels designed; with certain font and background color for each component on each of my panels. Is there any clean way to change font of jpanels and components on them? I mean I want to bind properties to my components; and as I changed the property; It's influence reflect on all of jpanels.

Comment: Have you played around with changing the Swing UIManager default values? If not, please have a look at Rob Camick's excellent article on this (with code): [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/).

Comment: yes I used look and feel in my program. But I say when all panels and components are initialized; and I want to change their properties using a clean way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JComponent#putClientProperty(Object key, Object value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) and this method could be used for multiple properties in one `JComponent`

Comment: +1 This is especially useful with a `PropertyChangeListener`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9346946/230513).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to investigate the use of different [Look and Feels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/). This will allow you to change pretty much any properties of your components, and you can even change the loof & feel dynamically at runtime.

Also see the answers to this question: [How do I get the default font for Swing JTabbedPane labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434201/default-font-for-swing-text)